# How to prevent cutoff of text portion of a checkbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a WrapPanel that is populated with a number of CheckBoxes:

```
<DockPanel>
    <WrapPanel
        DockPanel.Dock="Left"
        Name="wpnAttendees"
        Orientation="Vertical" />
</DockPanel>
```

that is populated as follows:

```
For Each p As Person In ocPeople
    chk = New CheckBox
    With chk
        .Content = "John Doe"   'p.FullName
        .FontWeight = FontWeights.DemiBold
        .Margin = New Thickness(0, 0, 3, 0)
        .Tag = p.PersonID
    End With
    AddHandler chk.Click, AddressOf EditAttendance
    wpnAttendees.Children.Add(chk)
Next
```

Here is a snapshot of part of the result.  Ignore the purplish border; that is just my monitor in the background of the window.

[image]

Note how the last column is partially hidden.  I thought using a scrollviewer was ideal for solving this problem but when I tried that it forced all the CheckBoxes into one row (or column).

How can I fix this?

Edit 1:  This is what I get by implementing ZiggZagg's idea.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple itemscontrol with both a scroll viewer and a wrap panel

```
<DockPanel>
    <ItemsControl Name="wpnAttendees" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>
</DockPanel>
```

The only adjustment you need to make to your code would be to change your code from

```
wpnAttendees.Children.Add(chk)
```

to

```
wpnAttendees.Items.Add(chk)
```

If you would like vertical orientation you can flip the scrolling from vertical to horizontal:

```
<ItemsControl Name="wpnAttendees" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Padding all CheckBoxes to the same length did not fix the problem.

Comment: If I set the Orientation of the WrapPanel to Vertical (which is necessary) I only get a single column inside the scroll viewer.

Comment: As noted in my previous comment,  that just leaves one vertical column of checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, but that is not what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can set padding in `<DockPanel padding="10">` or Margin in `<WrapPanel Margin="10">`